# Angular 2 Cli setup

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli

i want to clone Angular2 CLI 
so i created a folder  then i write this line in git bash
npm install -g angular-cli (from github)
but it show me this message :check this picture please  [git message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0xYv.png)

help me

Comment: "help me..." How?

Comment: check the message in the picture

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0xYv.png

Comment: My point is that you should ask a specific question rather than posting a console screen cap and expecting people to assume what kind of answer you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

all of these msg is just a '*warning*', you can ignore them.

you can start to use cli by type **ng new myApp2**
which will create new folder

or you can type **ng init** inside existing folder (which may ask to replace some file, be careful).